# Incrementing Shared Value in Database

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to create a polling system where user can select radio button and the choice will be incrementing in database

**insert_view.php**  - Simple form insertion for selecting the required fields

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php echo form_open('insert_ctrl'); ?>
 <h1>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter</h1><hr/>
 <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
  <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER>    <br>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php echo "which language do you prefer..?";?><br/>
  <?php echo form_radio(array('id' => 'rad1', 'name' => 'rad1','value'=>0)); ?>
  <?php echo form_label('JAVA'); ?> <?php echo form_error('rad1'); ?><br />

  <?php  echo form_radio(array('id' => 'rad2', 'name' => 'rad2','value'=>0)); ?>
  <?php echo form_label('PHP'); ?> <?php echo form_error('rad2'); ?><br />
  <?php echo form_radio(array('id' => 'rad3', 'name' => 'rad3','value'=>0)); ?>
  <?php echo form_label('C\C++'); ?> <?php echo form_error('rad3'); ?><br />

  <?php echo form_radio(array('id' => 'rad4', 'name' => 'rad4','value'=>0)); ?>
  <?php echo form_label('DOTNET'); ?> <?php echo form_error('rad4'); ?><br />

  <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

**insert_ctrl.php** - for sending the request through the help of controller from the view to the model.

```
  <?php
  class insert_ctrl extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->model('insert_model');
  }

  function index() {
  $data = array(

  'Option1' => $this->input->post('rad1'),   //for selecting the required option
  'Option2' => $this->input->post('rad2'),    //for selecting the required option
  'Option3' => $this->input->post('rad3'),    //for selecting the required option
  'Option4' => $this->input->post('rad4')
   );
   $vote = $this->input->post('Submit');

    if($vote=="Option1"){
   $value=$value+1;
   }
   elseif($vote=="Option2"){    
   $value=$value+1;
   }
   elseif($vote=="Option3"){
   $value=$value+1;
   }
   elseif($vote=="Option4"){
   $value=$value+1;
     }
    //Setting values for tabel columns

     //Transfering data to Model
     $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);


    //$data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
     //Loading View
      $this->load->view('insert_view', $data);
        }
      }
    ?>
```

**insert_model.php**

```
     <?php
     class insert_model extends CI_Model{
      function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      }
     function form_insert($data){
     // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
     $this->db->insert('students', $data);
      }
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: It's very good that we know exactly what you want.. you want it really bad.. now.. what's the problem? please don't repeat it more than 10 times.. thanks

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: great.. I want a BMW too.. But unfortunately I can't write here why I can't have it..

Comment: want to increment the value in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class name should start with capital letter,

```
class Insert_ctrl extends CI_Controller {
```

If the value to be incremented is in same table,then pass the value to model,

```
$data['value'] = $value;
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
```

And first of all what is the value of `$value`.??

If the value is present in different table,increment like this,

```
Update table name set value = value + 1 where question_id = id.
```

Instead of so many `if else`,

```
if($vote=="Option1" || $vote=="Option2" || $vote=="Option3" || $vote=="Option4"){
   $value=$value+1;
}
```

Comment: I created to increment it from the view only..but thanks